# Custom PayPal button?

Tags: javascript, paypal

Judging by all of the documentation that PayPal provides for the Express Checkout, they don't seem to want developers to create custom buttons for PayPal integrations.

The only JS method which they provide is `paypal.Button.render`, and this automatically renders a PayPal button to an element of your choosing. They then offer limited functionality [reference](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/styles) for styling this button (such as a circular or square button, and a choice of 3 colours).

The documentation I'm looking at is [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/add-paypal-button/#add-the-script-to-your-client).

My questions are:

- is it possible to style the button another way?
- is PayPal okay with me styling the button (are there any T&Cs stopping me)?

Perhaps there is a method which allows me to bind the pay click event to a more custom button.

*(please note, I don't want to completely rewrite my payment solution, I want to keep to the Express Payment method)*

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, I could I hide the actual button and place another button on top. I would make it so this newer button couldn't actually be clicked.

Looking at the demo [here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client).

CSS:

```
// Hide the actual button.
.paypal-button-container > * {
    visibility: hidden;
}

// Place a button over the top of the actual button.
#my-custom-button {
    pointer-events: none; // Not supported by IE10 and lower.
}
```

However, this method would not be supported by IE10 and lower. If this was the solution I went for, I would then show the actual PayPal button on IE10 and lower.

However, if PayPal changed their API, or started running checks for things like this, it could easily break my implementation.

Comment: I would recommend against this. As you mentioned, this is very likely to break in future, and could get you incorrectly flagged for an attempted click-jack against the iframe.